# Filter in Wireshark for TLS's Server Name Indication field

Tags: wireshark

Does wireshark have a filter for TLS's Server Name Indication field?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Shawn E's answer is probably the correct answer but my wireshark version doesnt have that filter. Following filters do exists, however:

To check if the SNI field exists:

```
ssl.handshake.extension.type == 0
```

or

```
ssl.handshake.extension.type == "server_name"
```

To check if an extension contains certain domain:

```
ssl.handshake.extension.data contains "twitter.com"
```

Comment: here's what worked for me: `tls.handshake.extensions_server_name contains "twitter.com"`

Answer (score 16):

`ssl.handshake.extensions_server_name`

Comment: Hello Shawn E. Although this might answer the question, can you provide some additional explanations? Maybe that would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 7):

Newer Wireshark has R-Click context menu with filters.

Find Client Hello with SNI for which you'd like to see more of the related packets.

Drill down to handshake / extension : server_name details and from R-click choose `Apply as Filter`.

See attached example caught in version 2.4.4

[image: SNI-WireShark-contextFilter]

Answer (score 2):

For a more complete example, here's the command to show SNIs used in new connections:

```
tshark -p -Tfields -e ssl.handshake.extensions_server_name \ 
    -Y 'ssl.handshake.extension.type == "server_name"'
```

(This is what your ISP can easily see in your traffic.)

Answer (score 2):

As google shows this up as first hit, the syntax has changed a bit (ssl renamed to tls):

tshark -r FILENAME.pcap -Tfields -e tls.handshake.extensions_server_name -Y 'tls.handshake.extension.type == 0'